# Open the Blog Posts by clicking on the Blog Categories

Tags: php

I have a blog page. I want that when a user Clicks on "All Posts", it should show all posts from Blog. And when someone clicks on a category like "Catering", it should show the posts from "Catering" category only.

Here is what i have did so far

```
<div class="blog-nav">
   <ul class="nav">
       <li><a>All Posts</a></li>

       <?php
       $SelectBlogcats  =   mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM blog GROUP BY cat_blog");
       while($row       =   mysqli_fetch_assoc($SelectBlogcats)){
       $Cat_query       = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cat_blog WHERE 
       id=".$row['cat_blog']);

       $main_cat        = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Cat_query);

       ?>

      <li><a><?php echo $main_cat['bcat_name'];?></a></li>

      <?php } ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The above seems quite lacking in substance. How is a user to select a different category for instance? I can see that within the `UL` you have anchor elements `a` but they will not do anything as they have no `href` attribute. Presumably you hope to generate a list of hyperlinks which, when clicked, issue a GET request to the same page and that selected category is used to filter the recordset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested and working answer

```
<?php
$cat_id=0;
$condition="";
if(isset($_GET['cat'])){
$cat_id=$_GET['cat'];
$condition="where cat_blog=$cat_id";                                
}

$SelectBlogcats =   mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM blog GROUP BY cat_blog");
    while($row      =   mysqli_fetch_assoc($SelectBlogcats)){
                                
    $Cat_query      = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cat_blog WHERE 
    id=".$row['cat_blog']);
    $main_cat       = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Cat_query);
                            ?>
<li>

<h2><a href="blog.php?cat=<?php echo $main_cat['id']; ?>"><?php echo $main_cat['bcat_name'];?></a></h2>
</li>
                            
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: perfectly working. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Some semi-pseudo code which might help you accomplish your goals - wholly untested however.

The nested sql queries you have is not very efficient and it is highly likely that a simple `join` between the tables is what you really need.

Each hyperlink used to select a new / different `category` to display needs to set ( in this example ) a querystring parameter which can be used to filter records from the entire recordset.

```
<?php
    /*
        Hopefully a single query should suffice
        joining the two tables rather than querying
        separately.
        
        Store the result of the query and use that to build
        the nav menu and also display the content late
    */
    
    $cat=!empty( $_GET['category'] ) ? $_GET['category'] : 'all';

    # without seeing the schema this is a guess!
    $sql='SELECT * FROM `blog` b 
        JOIN `cat_blog` cb on cb.`id`=b.`cat_blog`
        GROUP BY b.`cat_blog`';
    
    $res=$con->query( $sql );
    $rs=$res->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
    
    
?>
```

With the data stored in an associative array you can proceed to generate the hyperlink menu where each link has a querystring variable set; ie: `?category=X`

```
<div class="blog-nav">
   <ul class="nav">
       <li><a href='?category=all'>All Posts</a></li>
        <?php
            foreach( $rs as $row ){
                $active = $cat==$row['bcat_name'] ? ' class="active"' : '';
                printf( '
                    <li%2$s>
                        <a href="?category=%1$s">%1$s</a>
                    </li>
                    ',
                    $row['bcat_name'],
                    $active
                );
            }
        ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The recordset can then be processed again to output the actual blog content paying attention to the variable `$cat` to dictate which records are to be displayed.

```
<!-- blog display - ALL records or the filtered subset -->
<div class="blog-content">
    <?php
        
        if( !empty( $rs )){
            foreach( $rs as $row ){
                // display only the filtered category or ALL records
                if( $cat==$row['cat_name'] or $cat=='all' ){
                    /* output your blog content ..... */
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo 'There was an error fetching database records.';
        }

        $res->close();
    ?>
</div>
```